# Meteor: Add subdocument to existing record

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following Scheme:

```
dGroup = new SimpleSchema({
    title:      { type: String, optional: true },
    element:    { type: String, optional: true }
});

MongoDB.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title:      { type: String },
    slug:       { type: String, unique: true },
    language:   { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    group:      { type: [dGroup], optional: true },
}));
```

... and in the DB I got this:

```
{ "_id" : "ag9qXWpCYm87kZbEk", "title" : "Test", "slug" : "test", "language" : "en" }
```

Now I want to add a dGroup -> title:

```
updates['group.title'] = 'insert this as a new group title with no element';
MongoDB.update({ _id: Id }, { $push: updates }, function(error) { if(error) console.warn(error); });
```

But this doesn't work. So I need some help to add subdocuments in meteor in case they do not exist.

Comment: The docs say If the field is not an array, the operation will fail ($push). I think the child element is technically not an array? (title) Does it work with $set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your object first and push it properly, like this:

```
var newGroup = {
  title: 'insert this as a new group title with no element'
};
MongoDB.update({ _id: Id }, { $push: {group: newGroup }}, function(error) { if(error) console.warn(error); });
```

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between your code and mine?

Comment: Basically you were doing `MongoDB.update({ _id: Id }, { $push: {'group.title': 'some string'}})`. So in your case, Mongo expects the `dGroup.title` property to be an `Array` of `String`, but your Schema says otherwise: it says it's just a `String`. What you want to do is tell Mongo to push an `Object` (not a `String`) into `MongoDB.group`, which conveniently *is* defined as an `Array` of `Object` in your Schema.